# How can I get list of all user subscription data for an app on google play

Tags: google-api, google-play, in-app-subscription

Is there a Google play API that can list all the subscriptions (active, expired, cancelled) for an app?

I can see a developer API listed here - https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions using which I can only retrieve data for a single user. I am not looking for purchases by a single user but as an finance admin I want a list of all subscription purchases (active, expired, cancelled) every day so I can generate accrued/deferred revenue report for my company. Is there a way? Please assist.